# how can a find a stream associated with a file in code collaborator?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have this file on code collaborator and I want to see the version tree of the file. how should I proceed to find the stream or activity where this file is attached?

Answer (score 0):

The [user guide](http://support.smartbear.com/resources/cc/usersguide.pdf) mentions:

### Support for ClearCase UCM

> Collaborator supports ClearCase UCM activities. The change set associated with a
>   ClearCase activity can be added to a review using the Command Line Client `addactivity` command.
>   For each file in the activity, the latest version in the activity and the predecessor of the earliest version in the activity are uploaded to the review.

#### A Note about ClearCase Activities

> Uploading activities for review generates file differences based on Multiple Version
>   Changelists

So it depends on how that file has been uploaded to [CodeCollaborator](http://smartbear.com/products/software-development/code-review?_ga=1.105129156.632170566.1381851444), and if the "Multiple Change Changelist" name represents the UCM activity.

From the activity, you can then deduced the stream with [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).